# File locking technique in thread synchronization scenario is failing

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I was trying to write a class which let me do read and write operation on multiple files (like 5-10) while locking them from any kind of access. Everytime I access a file (doesn't matter if for read or write) a new file with the same name and a different extension is created, so other threads (belonging to different applications) are notified of the lock (ex. message.msg -> lock file message.lock created).

Every instance of the application will write in it's own file and read in all other applications files (including its).

Unfortunately, when I start several instances (like 3-4) of the application which uses this class, even if at first they look like they're working, then in a matter or seconds / maybe a couple of minutes it looks like one thread fails to release a file. This of course blocks the other threads too which are unable to read that specific file.

I say this because when everything app freezes I can see a permanent .lock file.

Of course I could put a Lock expire time (which probably would work in this scenario), but why is this happening?
To me this code looks reasonable, but of course I'm still a newbie...so...is there any mayor flaw in my ratio?

(Don't be scared by the length of this, they're only 2 functions and they do pretty much the same thing, except than for the central part)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace y3kMessenger
{
    static class FileLockAccess
    {
        public static string[] readAllLines(string path)
        {

            bool isLocked = false;

            string[] toReturn;

            string lockPath = path.Replace(Global.msgExtension, Global.lockExtension);

            StreamWriter w;

            //locking ...
            while (!isLocked)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(lockPath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (w = new StreamWriter(lockPath))
                        {
                            w.WriteLine(" ");
                        }

                        isLocked = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            //locked, proceed with read
            toReturn = File.ReadAllLines(path);


            //release the lock
            while (isLocked)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(lockPath);
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }

                isLocked = false;
            }

            return toReturn;

        }

        public static void writeLine(string path, string text, bool append)
        {

            bool isLocked = false;
            string lockPath = path.Replace(Global.msgExtension, Global.lockExtension);

            StreamWriter w;

            //locking ...
            while (!isLocked)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(lockPath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (w = new StreamWriter(lockPath))
                        {
                            w.WriteLine(" ");
                        }

                        isLocked = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            //locked, proceed with write
            using (w = new StreamWriter(path, append))
                w.WriteLine(text);

            //release the lock
            while (isLocked)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(lockPath);
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }

                isLocked = false;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: as an add to the discussion, the following code seems to work:

```
public static string[] readAllLines(string path)
{
    bool done = false;

    string[] toReturn = null;

    while (!done)
    {
        try
        {
            toReturn = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            done = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }


    }
    return toReturn;

}


public static void writeLine(string path, string text, bool append)
{
    bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                w.WriteLine(text);
            }

            done = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }


}
```

So the problem shouldn't reside in what threads are doing (I haven't changed anything else since the interface exposed by these methods is the same as the first 2)

Comment: Any kind of broken multi-threading locking scenario can produce deadlock.  Using a file as a lock is a particularly ineffective way to go about it.  Use a named mutex or semaphore, use a separate process to be the arbiter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem I see with your suggested approach is that DIFFERENT applications need to access the files. For as I have written this application, it can't communicate with other instances (they will be executed on different pc and will have in common just the smb filesystem) Is this maybe a scenario which leads to disasters no matter what?

Comment: This title of this question certainly is a disaster.  What on Earth does a borderless form have to do with any of this?

Comment: You're totally right. I dunno what has come to be written in the title, I clearly printed the wrong line...mistake corrected.